# Weak convergence in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of functions in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$,  with $1 \le p \le \infty$.

If $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\int_a^b f_n(x)dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx$$ for all $a,b$ ($a < b$), is it true that $(f_n)_n$ converges to $f$ weakly in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is "no".

The general theorem states that if $X$ is a Banach space and $(x_n)$ is a *bounded* sequence in $X$ and $x \in X$, sucht that $\alpha(x_n) \to \alpha(x)$ for all $\alpha$ from a *dense* subset of $X^\ast$, then $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ weakly.

In your case, you know that $\langle \mathbf 1_{[a,b]}, f_n \rangle \to \langle \mathbf 1_{[a,b]}, f \rangle$ and linear combinations of the characteristic functions of intervals are dense in $L^p$ (for $p < \infty$). But I do not believe you can get away without boundedness.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you give a proof of the general theorem you stated and say why the boundedness hypothesis is necessary?

Comment: The proof can be found, e.g. in Yosida, _Functional Analysis_, Theorem V.1.3, or pretty much any textbook on functional analysis that covers weak convergence.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Define $f_n$ to be the characteristic function of the interval $[n,2n]$. Set $f=0$.
Then 
$$
\int_a^b f_n dx = 0
$$
for $n>b$. However, $\|f_n\|_{L^p}=n^{1/p}$, and the sequence $(f_n)$ is unbounded in $L^p(\mathbb R)$, $p\in [1,\infty)$.

In case of $p=\infty$, set $f_n:= \sqrt n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$. Then $\|f_n\|_{L^1}=n^{-1/2}$, hence $f_n\to0$ in $L^1(\mathbb R)$. So your integral condition holds with $f=0$. However, $(f_n)$ is unbounded in $L^\infty$.